# An Active Directory Domain Controller for This Domain Could Not be Contacted with windows 7 laptop

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, samba, zentyal

I have server running Zentyal. And I have a problem with joining my domain. The problem exists with only my laptop. I've tried some other PC's and they successfully join the domain.

All the machines that I used run windows 7.

I tried to ping the domain controller from my laptop and it was successful. I also tried the other way around and that was also successful.

When I search Google I found some "fixes" that should work but they did not work for me.

1. I changed my dns server aadress to my domain controller.
2. I set my default gateway to domain controller ip but sill nothing.

Here's the error message that I get when I try to join the domain:

> The domain name "KK" might be a NetBIOS domain name.  If this is the
>   case, verify that the domain name is properly registered with WINS.
>
> If you are certain that the name is not a NetBIOS domain name, then
>   the following information can help you troubleshoot your DNS
>   configuration.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service
>   location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory
>   Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "KK":
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist." (error code 0x0000232B
>   RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

Comment: Just to be clear - do the zentyal server and the problem PC both point to the same DNS server?

Comment: Have you tried using the domain's fully-qualified name?  Is the laptop using the domain controller for DNS resolution?

Comment: Fix #2 (set default GW to the domain controller IP) doesn't look right. I'd undo this one if I were you - unless your domain controller is also a router.

Answer (score 1):

As Zentyal uses OpenLDAP for it's Domain system, Windows registry needs to be changed so it can communicate with it. There is already a guide on Zentyal's website to fix this issue:

http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/HowTo/Windows7Support

If your OS is up to date then you wont need to install the Hotfix and just go ahead with downloading the reg file and run it. After restart your computer and you are good to go.

If this doesn't fix your problem, make sure your Firewall is set so that they can communicate with the server.